# JSF: what is the "correct" way of doing this?

Tags: jsf

I've been using JSF for a while but there's something that has always confused me.  Hopefully someone can help.

Simple example, there's a page that shows a table of "Person"s and when you click on the "Person" name, it takes you to a page to view the details of the "Person".

Typically, I implement a personSearch.jsf page like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{personHandler.persons}" var="person">

    <h:column>
        <h:commandLink action="#{personHandler.show( person.id )}" >
            <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:column>

</h:dataTable>
```

And I implement a personView.jsf page like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">

    <h:outputText value="Person ID:" />
    <h:outputText value="#{personHandler.selectedPerson.id}" />

    <h:outputText value="Person Name:" />
    <h:outputText value="#{personHandler.selectedPerson.name}" />

</h:panelGrid>
```

PersonHandler.show(Integer personId) sets personHandler.selectedPerson and then redirects to the personView page.

This all works fine when PersonHandler is a session bean.  But I prefer it to be a request scoped bean because the user may have several windows open and I don't want there to be only one selected person per session.

So my question is, what's the "correct" way to do this JSF?  I was once able to get what I wanted using a4j:keepAlive on the personHandler, but that always felt like a kludge.  Again, this is something I've never understood about JSF.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view is supposed to be bookmarkable, pass the person ID as a GET request parameter instead of a POST request "parameter".

```
<h:outputLink value="viewperson.xhtml">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{person.id}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

This way you can use two `@RequestScoped` beans, one for the list and one for the view. You can preload the selected person as follows:

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")
private Long id;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedPerson = personDAO.find(id);
}
```

---

If it is not supposed to be bookmarkable, then just create a single view which renders the view state conditionally.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{!personHandler.viewMode}">
    <h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{personHandler.persons}" var="person">
            <h:column>
                <h:commandLink value="#{person.name}" action="#{personHandler.show(person)}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{personHandler.viewMode}">
    <h:form>
        ...
        <h:commandLink value="Go back" action="#{personHandler.back}" />
    </h:form>
</ui:fragment>
```

*(You can if necessary split out the content of the both framgents to another Facelet files which you include by `<ui:include>`)*

This way you can use a single `@ViewScoped` bean with action methods returning `void` or `null`.

```
public void show(Person selectedPerson) {
    this.selectedPerson = selectedPerson;
}

public void back() {
    selectedPerson = null;
}

public boolean isViewMode() {
    return selectedPerson != null;
}
```

You can even wrap the whole view in some

```
<h:panelGroup id="container">
```

and nest the following in both command links to let Ajax magic do the work

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render=":container" />
```

Comment: As always, a terrific answer!  Thanks BalusC.  My current application is designed differently though.  I have three separate pages personSearch.xhtml, personView.xhtml, and personForm.xhtml (for create/edit), because the layouts are very different on each page.  Would you suggest always using your GET params approach to navigate around?  What about times when I need to hit a method to do some processing before moving to the next page, can h:outputLink have an action pointing to a method?  Or alternately, can h:commandLink have parameters?  Thanks again (you should write a book!)

Comment: As to the different layouts, you surely do have a basic master layout (header/footer/menu/css/js which is same for all pages), do you? As to executing a method before navigating, then use a command link/button in combination with a redirect. And yes, a command link/button can have `<f:param>` as well or, often better, `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`.

Comment: There's a facelets template with "content" and "menu" sections defined, and each of the three pages per entity (search, view, and form) reference the template and define what goes in the content and menu sections.  Is that what you mean?  Each entity has a handler, ex PersonHandler with methods like doSearch, showViewPerson(Integer id), showModifyPerson(Integer id), doCreate, doModify, doDelete.  That's my basic design.  All the handlers are session based, but I'd much prefer them to be request based.  Is this design the wrong approach?  I'd appreciate any advice you have.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, each of the "show" and "do" methods return a string for navigation purposes.  For example, after create I go to the view page of the item that was created so on success personHandler.doCreate returns "personView" and so on.

Comment: Hi BalusC -- I'm trying to doing a simple get param example like you said, but I'm doing something wrong.  I posted a new question, if you could take a look I would greatly appreciate it! <removed>  Sorry, there was a stupid typing mistake in my example.  Got it now!  Thanks.